Data does not come in the query in Oda database in Android Kotlin
@Query("""
SELECT notes.*
FROM notes
INNER JOIN categories ON notes.categoryId = categories.id
WHERE categories.isPassword IS NULL OR categories.isPassword = 0
""")
fun getNotes(): Single<List<NoteData>>

I don't want to show notes if the category is encrypted.
At first, the notes in the encrypted category are not displayed, but when I remove the password of the category, they do not appear again.
The password issue in Note Data is not important to us, it only serves to encrypt the note.
Even if I make the query this way, the notes of the category whose password I removed no longer appear.
@Query("SELECT * FROM notes")
    fun getNotes(): Single<List<NoteData>>

NoteData
@Entity(tableName = "notes",
foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
    entity = CategoryData::class,
    parentColumns = ["id"],
    childColumns = ["categoryId"],
    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
)])
data class NoteData(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    var title: String? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    var description: String? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "category")
    var category: String? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "date")
    var date: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "isPassword")
    var isPassword: Boolean? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "images")
    var images: List<String>? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "categoryId")
    var categoryId: Int? = null
) : Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0
}

Category Data
@Entity(tableName = "categories")
data class CategoryData(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    var name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "isPassword")
    var isPassword: Boolean? = null
) : Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0
}

Database Module
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DatabaseModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): NoteDatabase =
        Room.databaseBuilder(context, NoteDatabase::class.java, "notes")
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDao(db: NoteDatabase) = db.getNoteDao()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideCategoryDao(db: NoteDatabase) = db.getCategoryDao()
}

